# How to insert a row into another table using ID of multiple tables

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

I am a novice in this area and would be grateful if i am provided solution to this challenge. I have a table called sql_product_name below

| product_code | product_name |
| --- | --- |
| 3001 | Scribble Book |
| 3002 | BIC Pen |

i also have another table called sql_product_cat

| cat_code | cat_name |
| --- | --- |
| 2001 | Text Book |
| 2002 | Ball Pen |

I also have another table called sql_PO and it has the following columns

| po_id | product_name(FK) | cat_name(FK) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3001 | 2001 |
| 2 | 3002 | 2002 |

I have a user-form that has two com-boxes filled with the actual product names and cat names. If i should select a product name and cat name, i want to insert into Table sql_PO the code numbers of the product and cat names and not the string names as i have done above in Table sql_PO. Because Table sql_PO has a relationship with Tables sql_product_name and sql_cat_name.

i saw this solution below and i thought i could use it but i don't know how to go about it in Mysql Workbench.

`output inserted.product_code,cat_code,0 into sql_PO(product_name, cat_name) Values  ('Scribble Book', 'Text Book')`

I would be grateful if i am helped. Thanks

Comment: I used the following query and it worked for me 'insert into sql_PO (product_code, cat_code) Values(Select product_code from sql_product where product_name = 'Scribble Book'), (Select cat_code from sql_product_cat from cat_name = 'Text Book')'